# Google Pay: Missing annotations Stripe React Native

Tags: android, react-native, stripe-payments

The Android builds in the Nx project are failing due to an error related to annotations when attempting to install the `stripe/react-native` package.

However, this issue does not arise when installing the package on a new project using the react-native CLI.

```
Task :stripe_stripe-react-native:packageDebugResources FAILED

Deprecated Gradle features were used in this build, making it incompatible with Gradle 8.0.

You can use '--warning-mode all' to show the individual deprecation warnings and determine if they come from your own scripts or plugins.

See https://docs.gradle.org/7.3.3/userguide/command_line_interface.html#sec:command_line_warnings
58 actionable tasks: 2 executed, 56 up-to-date
ERROR:/Users/esfxra/monorepo/apps/test-app/node_modules/@stripe/stripe-react-native/android/src/main/res/layout/googlepay_button_dark.xml: Resource and asset merger: /Users/esfxra/monorepo/apps/test-app/node_modules/@stripe/stripe-react-native/android/src/main/res/layout/googlepay_button_dark.xml is not annotated as @Input
java.lang.IllegalStateException: /Users/esfxra/monorepo/apps/test-app/node_modules/@stripe/stripe-react-native/android/src/main/res/layout/googlepay_button_dark.xml is not annotated as @Input
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':stripe_stripe-react-native:packageDebugResources'.
>! > /Users/esfxra/monorepo/apps/test-app/node_modules/@stripe/stripe-react-native/android/src/main/res/layout/googlepay_button_dark.xml: Error: is not annotated as @Input
```

Steps to reproduce the behavior:

- Run npm install @stripe/stripe-react-native
- Integrate the {...} component
- Run npx nx run wifi-app:run-android
- See error

Comment: Maybe that library is not compatible with Nx or there is some sort of conflict? Opening an issue on their repo might be a good first step.

Comment: Yeah there is already an open issue, seems like the team does not respond, if someone already fixed such issues they can assist here.

Comment: Seems like https://github.com/stripe/stripe-react-native/issues/1078 is pretty active and has some leads and workarounds, probably the best place to take this

Comment: There is no solution provided

Answer (score 0):

I approached this issue with this patch;

1. Delete the layout folder `node_modules/@stripe/stripe-react-native/android/src/main/res/layout`
2. Comment the layouts inside `initialize()` method of `node_modules/@stripe/stripe-react-native/android/src/main/java/com/reactnativestripesdk/GooglePayButtonView.kt`

```kotlin
package com.reactnativestripesdk

import android.view.LayoutInflater
import android.widget.FrameLayout
import com.facebook.react.uimanager.ThemedReactContext

class GooglePayButtonView(private val context: ThemedReactContext) : FrameLayout(context) {
  private var buttonType: String? = null

  fun initialize() {
  //  val type =
  //    when (buttonType) {
  //      "pay" -> R.layout.pay_with_googlepay_button
  //      "standard" -> R.layout.googlepay_button
  //      else -> R.layout.googlepay_button
  //    }

  //  val button = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(
  //    type, null
  //  )

  //  addView(button)
  }

  fun setType(type: String) {
    buttonType = type
  }
}
```

3. If you have added these dependencies into your `build.gradle` file, just comment them.

```
// implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.3.0'
// implementation 'com.stripe:stripe-android:20.12.+'
```

---

> **You need to do the same process whenever you execute `npm install` but if you want to automate this process follow the below steps.**

1. Create a shell script like this `patch.sh` and assign 777 permission, `sudo chmod +x patch.sh`

```bash
#!/bin/bash

ORIGINAL_DIR="node_modules/@stripe/stripe-react-native/android/src/main"
FIXED_DIR="patched_node_modules/@stripe/stripe-react-native/android/src/main"

# Remove the layout directory
rm -rf "$ORIGINAL_DIR/res/layout"

# Replace the file
cp "$FIXED_DIR/java/com/reactnativestripesdk/GooglePayButtonView.kt" "$ORIGINAL_DIR/java/com/reactnativestripesdk/GooglePayButtonView.kt"

echo "Successfully patched node_modules!"
```

2. Create a patched Kotlin file inside `patched_node_modules/@stripe/stripe-react-native/android/src/main/java/com/reactnativestripesdk/GooglePayButtonView.kt`

```kotlin
package com.reactnativestripesdk

import android.view.LayoutInflater
import android.widget.FrameLayout
import com.facebook.react.uimanager.ThemedReactContext

class GooglePayButtonView(private val context: ThemedReactContext) : FrameLayout(context) {
  private var buttonType: String? = null

  fun initialize() {
  //  val type =
  //    when (buttonType) {
  //      "pay" -> R.layout.pay_with_googlepay_button
  //      "standard" -> R.layout.googlepay_button
  //      else -> R.layout.googlepay_button
  //    }

  //  val button = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(
  //    type, null
  //  )

  //  addView(button)
  }

  fun setType(type: String) {
    buttonType = type
  }
}
```

3. Add `postinstall` script inside `package.json`

```json
  "scripts": {
    ...
    "postinstall": "./patch.sh"
  },
```

**That's it now until the Stripe team fixes this issue, we can survive.**

I'm still looking for better solution :)